# Don't like those synonyms

Tags: word, word-property

> Stand alone
>
> I am someone with authority
>
> Add a "B"  or  an "H" or  an "L"

> All three are synonyms of each other

Who am I?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think the answer is

> Ump

Stand alone
I am someone with authority

> Ump is short for "umpire" - an official who watches a game or match closely to enforce the rules

Add a "B" or an "H" or an "L"
All three are synonyms of each other

> **B**ump, **H**ump and **L**ump are all, essentially, synonyms of each other (a protuberance).

Explanation of the Title (from OP in the comments)

> Bumps, humps and lumps are often disliked (especially on one's body).

Comment: Well at least it took an hour :). Gives me cheap thrill!

Comment: Nyfb gubfr guerr guvatf (rfcrpvnyyl ba lbhe obql) ner qvfyvxrq. Urapr gur gvgyr.

Comment: @DrD Ah, okay, got it.